# Way to make WPF DockPanel auto-resize based on its children's size?

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

Right now I have a DockPanel that contains a toolbar and BrowserWindow. When I re-size the BrowserWindow to fit content, I want that change to propagate up into the DockPanel and re-size automatically. Is there a setting for this?

So the layout of my app is essentially:

```
-Browser Control Class

--DockPanel

----Toolbar (docked to Top)

----Browser Window Class

------Grid

--------Menu

--------Embedded Browser
```

Basically I want the size that I set on my Browser Window Class to automatically re-size the DockPanel.

Before applying size to Browser Window:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py8Sc.jpg]

After applying size to Browser Window (I want to get rid of that extra space surrounding the embedded browser):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxLju.jpg]

Comment: Are you saying that it will shrink, but not grow?

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you make the dock-panel resize you still have extra space but around the dock-panel.

Comment: I set a size on the BrowserWindow. But the DockPanel is still the same size as before and didn't automatically re-size. That's why there's that white space between the toolbar and the BrowserWindow in the second picture. I want the DockPanel to re-size automatically to any changes in the BrowserWindow size.

If I re-size the DockPanel, why would I still have extra white space? The only thing above it in the tree is my UserControl class.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you specify `Width="Auto"`?

Answer (score 2):

DockPanel has a [LastChildFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill.aspx) property that you can use. Try to play with it a little. Remember that BrowserWindow needs to be the last child in DockPanel.

I think you will also have to change something in your Grid. By LastChildFill property should be set. You are on right track at least.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `DockPanel` to a `StackPanel`, put it inside a `Grid`, and set it's `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Center`

You might also need to play with the the `Height`/`Width` of the `WebBrowser` to specify the initial size

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Menu />
        <WebBrowser Height="SomeValue" Width="SomeValue" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```